# Handling and Formatting Date in Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: database, excel, oracle, date, format

Below is the Excel sheet I work with, it has two coulmns Name and Date

I need to insert data in the excel sheet to my oracle DB using insert statements give below, but when I try to get the date values it shows as a number, Could someone please tell me how can I get the real date value to my insert statement.
my formula is like this

="insert into mm values('"&TRIM(A2)&"','"&TRIM(B2)&"');"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
="insert into mm values('"&TRIM(A2)&"','"&TRIM(TEXT(B2, "dd/mm/yyyy"))&"');"
```

output:

> insert into mm values('CLND.W0005','02/01/2009');